# How can i give a image path in jquery?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

How to change image path in jquery, i want to change this image path:

```
loader_path: 'images/prettyPopin/loader.gif'
```

i used this code but not work

```
loader_path: '<?php echo theme_img('prettyPopin/loader.gif'); ?>
```

Comment: you're missing closing quote..?

Comment: Is this jQuery?! This is php...

Answer (score 1):

```
loader_path: '<?php echo theme_img('prettyPopin/loader.gif'); ?>'
```

you're missing closing quote.. – [Sudhir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350858/sudhir)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"<?php echo theme_img('prettyPopin/loader.gif'); ?>"
```

Don't Mix quotes

`prettyPopin/loader.gif` is string not a variable